# Connection error while trying to run multiple test scenarios via Selenium Grid

Tags: testing, automation, selenium-grid, sencha-test

I've created a Selenium grid with 5 nodes connected to the hub. Then I tried to run multiple Sencha Test scenarios through the hub. The test run started and after few minutes the tests stopped with errors shown below:

Failed with error "connect EADDRINUSE localhost:4556"
Global leaks check threw an error: connect EADDRINUSE localhost:4556

Could you help us to find a solution for this? It seems like issue is that hub server getting overloaded with huge number of input requests.

Thanks,
Anand.